# Timer of TEX-compilation through WinEdt

Tags: macros, winedt

Is there a way to get the TeX compilation time (texify, pdflatex, etc) by some commands in a WinEdt macro? The system i have is win 7. There is a system command time.exe returning something like 13:09:43.67. Here 44.67 is seconds and miliseconds. How to get them into a WinEdt string? I need analyze time up to msecs, not merely seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinEdt has two macro to control the elapsed time: `StartTimer` and `GetTimer`.

The first resets the timer to be used by the latter, which returns the elapsed time since the last call to `StartTimer` in milliseconds in an internal register.

So, if you want to know how much time WinEdt takes to perform compiling a file, you can do the following:

1. Create a file `Timer.edt` with the following contents:

   ```
   EnterReg(0,"Which compiler do you want to use (e.g. PDFLaTeX)?","Choose the compiler");
   PushTagsandRegisters;
   StartTimer;
   Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\%!0.edt');
   GetTimer(0);
   Prompt("Elapsed Time (msec): %!0");
   PopTagsandRegisters;
   End;
   ```

   and save it in the directory `%b\Macros` where `%b` is the local AppData folder of WinEdt (it is usually `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team` and can be retrieved in the "Configuration Wizard" interface, "Options" menu)
2. Show the "Options Interface" ("Options" -> "Options Interface")

   [image]
3. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (a local copy of `MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
4. Just after the lines

   ```
   MENU="TeX_Menu"
     CAPTION="Te&X"
     CONFIG_FILTER="Default;MiKTeX;TeX Live"
   ```

   add the lines

   ```
     ITEM="Timer"
       CAPTION="Timer"
       IMAGE="Time"
       MACRO="Exe('%b\Macros\Timer.edt');"
       REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

---

That's it. Now you have a menu item "Timer" in the "TeX" menu.

[image]

When you want to know, for example, how much time WinEdt takes to `pdlatex` your `.tex` file, press that item when the `.tex` file is in the foreground and you will be prompted with

[image]

and write "PDFLaTeX".

After the compilation you will be prompted with something like

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I  am in older version of WinEdt, 5.6. So is there other means to solve the problem?

Comment: @maximav No, unfortunately `StartTimer` and `GetTimer` have been introduced in v7, IIRC. Why don't you upgrade to v8.1? You would be able to play with a lot of new features...

Comment: Ah, Good feature I wasn't aware of. But I was expecting you Karl :-) Nice.

Comment: Nevertheless, can someone hint how to extract to a WinEdt macro the Windows command echo %TIME% which produces the current system time?!. One can get even some digits from it. Say, echo %TIME:~-4% gives the four last digits from the system time resulting from echo %TIME%. Great thanks to experts in advance!

Comment: @maximav A lot of things has changed since WinEdt 5... I don't remember how macros worked in v5. Try `WinExe('','cmd.exe /C echo %%TIME%% > foo.txt','%p','',011100);ReadFile('%p\foo.txt');Prompt('%!0');` to prompt the result of `echo %TIME%` (it works in v8).

Comment: Thanks a superlot!. How great to deal with a guru. It helped me though this WinEdt's commands didnt work for me. Here is my correction which works in WinEdt 5.6 on Windows 7. WinExe('','cmd.exe /C echo %%TIME%%','%O','',1011,1,'','foo.txt','');

Comment: @maximav Happy to help. If you really want to thank me you can accept the answer.

Comment: Oh! No problem. What I have to do? What "accept" means? Where to click?

Comment: @maximav See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). Probably you will accept some old answers, too.

Comment: Hi, Karl again. Everything works nice. Now suppose I get two files foo1.txt and foo2.txt with two times, say 12.09.44.09 and 12.09.45.03. How can I get their difference, ie. 94 miliseconds?

Comment: @maximav If you are sure they are in that format, use `ReadFile("foo1.txt",1); SubstituteInString("%!1",".","",0,1); ReadFile("foo2.txt",2); SubstituteInString("%!2",".","",0,2); LetRegNum(3,%!2-%!1); Prompt("%!3");`

Comment: Thanks so much again. I found some more string functions and completely solved the problem. Of course, I trust that version 8 much better but one needs time to migrate and tune the new WinEdt's interface and, especially, some new philosophy in macroprogramming.